# Mac App: 'Auto Loading' the last used Document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I'm currently writing a document based application, and was curious to how I would load the most recently used document ('File > Open Recent'section) by default at application startup? Any good info on this or code snippets? New to Obj-C

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your application delegate, you'd want to implement applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    NSURL *lastURL=[[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (lastURL!=nil)
    {
        [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:lastURL display:YES error:nil];  
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Apparently, the default NSDocument-based cocoa app in XCode doesn't come with an AppDelegate.  Weird.  To add one:

- Add a new class to your Project, call it MyAppDelegate, or whatever you want.
- In the interface for MyAppDelegate, add the protocol NSApplicationDelegate, it should look something like this:

  @interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
  {
  }
- Open up MainMenu.xib
- Drag an Object instance to the xib's window, the Object instance looks like a blue box.
- Select the Object instance and in the inspector, go to the Identity tab (the blue i)
- Set the Class to MyAppDelegate
- Select the "Application" in the xib
- In the inspector, click on the Connections tab (the blue arrow icon) and drag from "delegate" to the application delegate you just set up.

You are good to go now.

Comment: so this would go in my main (.m) file? myDocument.m?

Comment: Jon, 
What would I substitute for the docController? My document name is MyDocument, but that's pulling a warning that it may not respond.. and it doesn't work also

Comment: The answer is in the first four words of Jawngee's response.

Comment: Josh, 
Being new to cocoa, I'm still learning what an application delegate is.. I've literally been using XCode for about a week. Would that be my .m file? But like I said, that's not the issue anymore, the issue is what docController is. Do i need to make an IBOutlet called docController and attach it to the window? Or is it supposed to be something else? I'm having trouble implementing this

Comment: The default NSDocument project in XCode doesn't generate an Application delegate.

Comment: Jawngee! Thank you very much for your help that worked like a charm. I appreciate the easy wording, things can get confusing sometimes (being new to XCode and the like). Anyway, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So the above code is almost perfect.  The only problem I ran into is that if this is a new application, then the list of recentDocumentURL's may be empty (or nil), so the ask to get objectAdIndex:0 of a nil array will cause problems.  I would suggest putting the following code right after the method declaration.

```
NSArray *list = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs];
if ((list == nil) || ([list count] == 0))
    return YES;
```

The error I am trying to avoid is as follows:

> 2014-01-28 17:02:33.042 jNotebook[8144:303] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array